# Trying to drag and drop a bootstrap child modal outside of a parent modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'm working on a real project trying to find a way to drag a bootstrap child modal outside of a parent modal. One way I've been able to do that is by moving the child modal to another `<div>` outside of the parent. I did this by using jQuery's $().detach().appendTo(). Is it possible to create the same behavior without moving the child modal element?

Here is a simplified example and a working plunk (http://plnkr.co/JwWJbZ3NR44xaCpoXZ3g?p).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
    Open Parent Modal
  </button>

  <div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header brown-color">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Parent Modal</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body light-brown-color">
            <p>This is the parent body...</p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name..." />
            <br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name..." />
            <br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Address..." />
            <br />
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Write here..."></textarea>

            <div>
              <!-- Button trigger modal -->
              <button type="button" id="childbutton" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
                Open Child Modal
              </button>

              <!--Adding child modal-->
              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header brown-color">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                      </button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Child Modal</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body ex-light-brown-color">
                      <p>This is the child body...There are different ways one can create the modals. This is called a static modal. </p>
                      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Write here..."></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer brown-color">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.modal fade -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal -->

            <!--End of child modal-->

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer brown-color">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal fade -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal -->

  <!--Move child modal here. -->
  <div id="testdiv"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.modal-dialog').draggable();
    $('#myModal2').detach().appendTo('#testdiv');
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: What should happen once the modal is outside?

Comment: It needs to be movable and writable for data entry. The user needs to move the child modal on the screen to view and write parent modal information.  Right now the current code I'm using here is causing issues within other areas of our code. If the element could remain within the parent div I feel it could solve my problem. Otherwise,  I’ll have to address other code issues.